# Hover class removed onload when cursor over item in jQuery

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-hover

I'm building a site with a jQuery hover function that swaps out the current image with that in `data-hover-src` and adds the class 'hover' to the `.product-overlay` so that I can use CSS to show it when the user hovers over each list item.

All pretty simple stuff, however, if the user has their cursor over the list item when the page loads, my code does the reverse of what I want i.e. it *removes* the `.hover` class on mouseout.

Is there a way to make sure that the `.hover` class is only added when the cursor is over the list item?

Thanks,

Osu

**HTML**

```
<ul class="product-listing">
 <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="product-images">
      <img src="{src1}" data-hover-src="{src2}">
    </a>
    <span class="product-overlay hidden">
      Overlay content
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
  ...etc.
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQUERY**

```
// Hoverswap function
  var hoverSwap = function () {
    var $this       = $(this).find('img');
    var overlay     = $(this).find('.product-overlay');
    var newSource     = $this.data('hover-src');
    $this.data('hover-src', $this.attr('src')); // Show original source if hover-src is showing
    $this.attr('src', newSource); // Vice versa
    if( overlay.hasClass('hover') ) {
      overlay.removeClass('hover');
    } else {
      overlay.addClass('hover');
    }
  }

// Run function
$('.product-listing li').hover(hoverSwap, hoverSwap);
```

**JSFIDDLE**

Here's an example of how it's set up - this is just to see the hover over function, I can't reproduce the problem I'm seeing with this fiddle for some reason...

http://jsfiddle.net/wn7t7kh7/

**VIDEO**

...so here's a video of what's happening to make it clearer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaslRbKGdKM

Comment: I can't find any issue with the fiddle mate..

Comment: Ah, I realise the fiddle isn't actually showing the behaviour (probably because it is loading all the HTML and images before the JS - I'm working on a private Shopify site with this where I'm seeing the problem. Ideally I could share a direct link, but that's not possible at this point. Is there any way to check if there is a 'mouseover' onload of the page and then modify my code to show/hide the `.hover` class accordingly?

Comment: Or maybe check if the overlay is 'visible' first?

Comment: you could try checking whether the images are loaded before the hover function is executed

Comment: Thanks Outlooker - I've added a video to the description of this question to show you what I'm seeing on the site as obviously this is hard to fix without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry mate,I really have no chance of accessing youtube right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I needed to use the plugin [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) as it seems a slight delay is needed before running the 'hoverswap' function for it to work the way it's intended. The code I am using is:

```
$('.product-listing li').hoverIntent({
        over: hoverSwap,
        out: hoverSwap,
        interval: 10
});
```

I tried doing the same thing with just a `delay` in the chain i.e.

```
$('.product-listing li').delay(100).hover(hoverSwap, hoverSwap);
```

But this didn't work, hence the need for a plugin. If anyone has a solution that doesn't require a plugin, please share as I'm keen to learn alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this might help cause I can't really see the issue.Try checking these steps

1.You could try checking if all the images are loaded in your website before performing the script action. It is easier to check that all image and everything else has loaded by using the [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

Try using

```
$(window).load(function() { 
     //Your code here
 });
```

To check whether an element is visible you could try making use of the [**:visible**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

Example

```
$("#selector:visible" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).css( "height", "100px" );
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it hasn't solved the issue. I'm a little stuck as to what to do to be honest...

Comment: could you share ur website link.If its accessible wil try to help u out

Comment: It's password-protected at this stage, so if you're happy for me to pass you the details privately, then we can post the solution here assuming we find it - what's the best way to reach you?

Comment: could u provide a gif image of your situation.I think that would be alright

Comment: Have a look at the description, I've put a video of what is happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaslRbKGdKM and if you need a gif, here: http://share.gifyoutube.com/vMlQob.gif

Comment: I really don't kno if this might work.Could u try adding `$(".product-overlay").removeClass("hover");` after `$('.product-listing li').hover(hoverSwap, hoverSwap);`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either - I'm going to try the hoverintent plugin, might solve the issue based on what I can see